# Entity Framework .Include creating an incorrect JOIN?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

This is my first attempt at using EF with the .include in order to JOIN two tables. When I run it I get and error that "CallStatus_Id" is an invalid column. That is correct, I don't have that field in the table but I don't know why EF is using that in it's SQL query.

What I did was create a Foreign Key on my CustomerCall table that sets the CustomerCall.Status to CallStatus.Id together. The idea is that I store the PK value in the CustomerCall.Status field and JOIN that to the CallStutus.Id so that I can get the CallStatus.StatusName for display purposes.

Here is my lambda expression:

```
var call = db.CustomerCalls.Include(s => s.CallStatus).Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

My understanding of the lambda would be that it calls the CustomerCalls table, JOIN it to the CallStatus table using the FK that was created and the WHERE statement would pull the Id of the CustomerCall based on the id that was passed into the repository method.

It creates the following SQL. You can see in the JOIN it creates [Extent1].[CallStatus_Id] which is incorrect. I don't have that column, it should be [Extent1].[Status] and I don't how to correct it

These are my EF Entity classes:

```
namespace CPPCustomerCall.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("CustomerCall")]
    public partial class CustomerCall
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CallDate { get; set; }

        public int? Status { get; set; }

        public int? AssignedTo { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }


        public CallStatus CallStatus { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace CPPCustomerCall.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class CallStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create your foreign key manually or via EF code first?

Comment: I did it in SQL Server. Am I supposed to to it in EF?

Comment: You need to specify it somehow in the code, because by default EF doesn't know that you have already created FK.

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestions posted here it looks like I got it to work by adding the [ForeignKey("Status")] annotation to my CallStatus navigation property in my  CustomerCall entity. I also needed to set the [Key] on the Id field of my CallStatus entity.

```
public partial class CustomerCall
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CallDate { get; set; }

        public int? Status { get; set; }

        public int? AssignedTo { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Status")]
        public CallStatus CallStatus { get; set; }

    }

public partial class CallStatus
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(25)]
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
    }
```